# Birt report silent print

Tags: printing, report, birt

I'm using `BIRT` report engine.

When report is opened, I press `Print report` button and this steps I should proceed to print my report.

1. Print report dialog shows. I should choose print format (HTML) and page range (All pages).
2. Click "OK". New window with report preview opens.
3. Print dialog shows. Click `OK` => the report is printing.
4. Need to close this popup window and original report window.

Is there any `Silent` or `Auto-print` functions in `BIRT`?